# How to get math.random to work?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I wrote this code with math.random to make a random number between 1 to 3 but when I press click me button, it only give +3 it doesn't random between 1 to 3.

I want it to give between 1 to 3 when I click the button.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0k3c0x2x/6/)

```
var cookies = 0; 
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1; 
if(localStorage.cookies)
  cookies = localStorage.getItem('cookies');    
document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies; 
function cookieClick(number) {
  cookies = parseInt(cookies) + rand;
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
  localStorage.setItem('cookies', cookies); 
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/0k3c0x2x/9/

Comment: Each time I run the script, I get a number between 1 and 3. If you are expecting `rand` to be different every time you click the button, you are mistaken. `rand` will remain the same through the entire script, since you save that value without ever recalculating the random number

Comment: I see, you edited your post. If you want a new random number every time you click the button, you need to generate the number on every click, not at the top of the script: http://jsfiddle.net/0k3c0x2x/14/

Answer (score 0):

Generate your random number each time the button is clicked, not at the top of the script. Also, why are you subtracting 1 from 3 then adding it right back?:

```
function cookieClick(number){
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  cookies = parseInt(cookies) + rand;
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
  localStorage.setItem('cookies', cookies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the % on your variable rand.

Ex:

```
var val = rand % 3;
if(val == 0){
   val = 1;
}
```

-OR

```
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the random number once instead of generating a new one every time the `button` is pressed. You need to generate a new random number on every button press. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0k3c0x2x/15/

Answer (score 0):

Your code works properly, you are only generating the random number once. If you were to delete your cache and reload the page you would generate a different number. I got +2 on your page for example.

You need to generate a new random number inside your button click.

```
function cookieClick(number){
cookies = parseInt(cookies) + Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
localStorage.setItem('cookies', cookies);}
```